# Unable to add a static route: SIOADDRT: Network is unreachable

Tags: networking, linux-networking, route

I've been bashing my head against a wall for a few days trying to figure this out:
My ifconfig is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:BB:XX:XX
          inet addr:192.168.36.132  Bcast:192.168.37.255  Mask:255.255.254.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:BB:XX:XX
          inet addr:116.xx.xx.xx    Bcast:116.xx.xx.xx    Mask:255.255.255.192
```

When I try and add a static route to go out of eth0, I get the following error:

```
servername-test:/ # route add -net 10.248.12.0 netmask 255.255.255.240 gw 192.168.36.254 dev eth0 
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

My Default gateway is:

```
servername-test:~ # netstat -anr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
116.xx.xx.xx    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U         0 0          0 eth1
192.168.238.0   192.168.36.254  255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.239.0   192.168.36.254  255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.36.0    192.168.36.254  255.255.254.0   UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 lo
0.0.0.0         116.xx.xx.xx    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
```

`ip route list` output

```
116.66.240.64/26 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 116.xx.xx.xx 
192.168.238.0/24 via 192.168.36.254 dev eth0 
192.168.239.0/24 via 192.168.36.254 dev eth0 
192.168.36.0/23 via 192.168.36.254 dev eth0
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo scope link 
default via 116.xx.xx.xx dev eth1
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of `/sbin/ip addr` and `/sbin/ip route`? These are more useful for debugging than ifconfig and netstat.

Comment: ip route:`116.66.240.64/26 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 116.xx.xx.xx
192.168.238.0/24 via 192.168.36.254 dev eth0
192.168.239.0/24 via 192.168.36.254 dev eth0
192.168.36.0/23 via 192.168.36.254 dev eth0
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
default via 116.xx.xx.xx dev eth1
`

Comment: `2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.36.132/23 brd 192.168.37.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 116.xx.xx.xx/26 brd 116.xx.xx.xx scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: I meant please edit your original post and include the information I requested. Pasting that output into the comments makes it entirely unreadable.

Comment: i also faced the same issue with my HPUX servers while adding the default route because i was unable to access the servers which are available in outside of my network. so [i got the correct command to add the default and to check the routing table in hpux here](http://expertisenpuru.com/1-easy-command-to-add-default-route-in-hpux/) you also can try, I hope this may help you to solve your problem too :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have not declared `192.168.36.0/23` link local, despite the fact you have an address assigned for it, no link-local route appears to be listed in your routes.

```
192.168.36.0    192.168.36.254  255.255.254.0   UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.36.0/23 via 192.168.36.254 dev eth0
```

Instead its declared `192.168.36.0/23` should be passed to the gateway `192.168.36.254` which technically according to the rest of the routing table does not appear to be a neighbour (the kernel has no idea how to get to `192.168.36.254`).

There should be no gateway assigned for `192.168.36.0/23` because according to your IP address `192.168.36.132/23` it is probably meant to be a a link-local range (neighbours directly responsive via ARP).

You *should* have an entry such as this instead:

```
192.168.36.0    0.0.0.0  255.255.254.0   U        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.36.0/23 dev eth0 scope link
```

To fix, you need to remove the gateway declaration for `192.168.36.0/23` and replace with an entry such as:

```
ip route add 192.168.36.0/23 dev eth0
```

Comment: This is the problem! I don't know what is causing it though. Somewhere on this server the ip address is being declared wrong, though I can't see where.

Answer (score 0):

If so, forget command line, just append the Ethernet file entry directly and 'service network restart'. That works!
I feel computer silly, because it irritated me first - then same route works perfectly while adding forcefully into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I had added this answer  before formatting, the problem is about network system of computer, there was a problem about network card. None of the solutions worked. I had to change the motherboard.
Edit2: You may have connected the cable to the wrong place, double check your cables.

Comment: In a sense, can't this "solution" be used to solve every similar problem? Is this a useful solution to this specific problem?

Comment: @Paul We think the motherboard is problematic. This can't help every solution but there can be people like me, struggling 5 hours or more, maybe this may help them figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score -4):

(Qouting) Whevener will add the default route need to specify a metric of 1 and execute the route add command:

Execute the below command to add default route in HPUX:

```
#route add default 192.168.178.1 1
add net default: gateway 192.168.178.1
```

Default route is added.

According to this http://expertisenpuru.com/1-easy-command-to-add-default-route-in-hpux/