# Debian BeagleBone Black inaccessible via SSH/ping over ethernet

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp, linux-networking, route

Somewhat related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/581159/unable-to-add-a-static-route-sioaddrt-network-is-unreachable).  I have a BeagleBone Black running Debian and am trying to use its ethernet port for internet (rather than USB sharing as is typical when getting it up and running).

However, I can't seem to get it to connect to the internet properly.  For reference, I am connecting it to the network at work, and am behind a firewall.  It seems to be assigned an incorrect IP address, based on the other devices on my network.  It is inaccessible via SSH or ping to the 10. address, however I can still SSH based on the USB static IP address.

I'm not exactly sure what the real issue is here, if I simply can't access it because its on another subnet at work, or if there is some conflict between the USB static IP and the DHCP-assigned IP for eth0, or something else.

If anybody can suggest troubleshooting steps, or if this is an easy fix, I'd appreciate it!

**route:**

```
Kernel IP routing table                                                           ~
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface     ~
default         10.54.50.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0      ~
10.54.50.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0      ~
10.54.50.1      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0      ~
192.168.7.0     *               255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 usb0
```

**/etc/resolv.conf:**

```
domain localdomain
search localdomain
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

**ipconfig:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:ec:eb:a3:fa:77
          inet addr:10.54.50.185  Bcast:10.54.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6eec:ebff:fea3:fa77/64 Scope:Link          
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:3412 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0      
          TX packets:201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0    
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                             
          RX bytes:422494 (412.5 KiB)  TX bytes:25952 (25.3 KiB)  
          Interrupt:40                                           

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback                            
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0                 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host                     
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1          
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                    
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                             
          RX bytes:12960 (12.6 KiB)  TX bytes:12960 (12.6 KiB)                 

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:ec:eb:a3:fa:70                      
          inet addr:192.168.7.2  Bcast:192.168.7.3  Mask:255.255.255.252    
          inet6 addr: fe80::6eec:ebff:fea3:fa70/64 Scope:Link              
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1              
          RX packets:552 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0           
          TX packets:121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0        
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                 
          RX bytes:61748 (60.3 KiB)  TX bytes:18365 (17.9 KiB)
```

**ip route list:**

```
default via 10.54.50.1 dev eth0  
10.54.50.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.54.50.185                
10.54.50.1 dev eth0  scope link                                                   
192.168.7.0/30 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.7.2
```

The last point is that eth0 is on the 10. network, however my other devices that are plugged in are all on the 141. network.  I'm not sure if this is because its contacting the wrong DHCP server, or if somehow that particular plug is looking to the wrong spot.

**Edit:** when I try to add a route to what I imagine is the 'correct' gateway, I see the following:

```
root@beaglebone:~# /sbin/route add default gw 141.210.154.1 eth0
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the issue wasn't on my end, it was within IT.  The device wasn't registered to the appropriate domain.  Once that was fixed, the correct IP was automatically assigned.